# How to add a banner to a Javascript bundle while using BannerPlugin and TerserPlugin?

Tags: webpack

I want to add some information like version to the top of the code after minify.What should I do?

```
optimization: {
    minimizer: [
      new TerserPlugin({
        cache: true,
        parallel: true,
        sourceMap: false,
        terserOptions: {
          output: {
            comments: false
          }
        }
      })
    ]
  }
```

Answer (score 3):

Use the "preamble" option.

```
optimization: {
minimizer: [
  new TerserPlugin({
    cache: true,
    parallel: true,
    sourceMap: false,
    terserOptions: {
      output: {
        preamble: "/* HEADER */"
        comments: false
      }
    }
  })
]
}
```

Answer (score 1):

For anyone wondering how to do this with BannerPlugin, the TerserPlugin can be configured to retain anything needed for a specific project with a regex. For instance, legal/licensing, etc.

In the BannerPlugin text you want to include, add something to regex against in order to retain it in the generated files. For instance, the banner text may be something like: `@banner My banner message`

And the TerserPlugin configuration to retain it would look like:

```
            new TerserPlugin({
                terserOptions: {
                    output: {
                        comments: /@banner/i
                    }
                },
                extractComments: false
            })
```

Feel free to check the TerserPlugin documentation on retaining comments, there are other examples there.

Answer (score 0):

There is a newer question which is kind of same as this, where I just posted possible solution - https://stackoverflow.com/a/67241531/1979530 - without checking if older question exist.

The gist is that you can't, or at least not in an elegant way - BannerPlugin hooks on compilation, one should hook on emit. Look at `BannerAfterMinimizePlugin` example and implement as you wish.