# Webpack: Insert header in minified JS file

Tags: webpack

I am trying to insert a header (comment) on top of my minified JS files.

```
const banner: [
    '/**!',
    `@name    : ${package.name}`,
    `@version : ${package.version}`,
    `@date    : ${new Date().getUTCDate()}/${new Date().getUTCMonth() + 1}/${new Date().getUTCFullYear()}`,
    '*/'
    ].join('\n');
```

For this, I am using `webpack.bannerPlugin`.

```
new webpack.BannerPlugin({
    banner: banner,
    raw: true,
    entryOnly: true
})
```

But now I am forcing the issue that the banner seems to be removed by the minification process of `babelMinifyPlugin`. I tried to use a Regex but it did not fix my problem.

```
new babelMinifyPlugin({}, {
    comments: '/^\**!|@name|@version|@date/'
}),
```

I am not quiet sure *how* the Regex in the Plugin actually works. For me, it should pass all comments which begin with

- `/*!`,`/**!`, ... or
- `@name` or
- `@version` or
- `@date`

But this not happens. The banner is inserted properly when I use my development config (without minification), but when using it with my production config (with minification) it is not added.
So how is the Regex of the `babelMinifyPlugin` actually working?

Answer (score 1):

To get you started in webpack config JS file declare and define plugin, that hooks on emit, not compile (as does `webpack.BannerPlugin`, see references).

I'm using ES2015+ (current Node.js LTS which is 14 as of writing should be able to support [up to ES2020](https://node.green)) and ECMAScript modules, not CommonJS in my webpack config, and thus so will my example, translate if necessary.

```js
// ----------------

import {
  ConcatSource
} from 'webpack-sources';

// ----------------

class BannerAfterMinimizePlugin {
  constructor ({
    banner = '',
    raw = true
  }) {
    this.raw = raw;
    this.banner = raw ? banner : `/*${banner}*/`;
  }

  apply (compiler) {
    compiler.hooks.emit.tapAsync('BannerAfterMinimizePlugin', (compilation, callback) => {
      compilation.chunks.forEach((chunk) => {
        chunk.files.forEach((file) => {
          compilation.updateAsset(
            file,
            (old) => new ConcatSource(this.banner, '\n', old)
          );
        });
      });
      callback();
    });
  }
}

// TODO:
// add key that would result in banner being applied
// only to chunks that satisfy regex
// i.e., to address extensions / chunk names
```

and now later in the webpack config use it

```js
// ----------------
// BannerAfterMinimizePlugin
if (!tierIsDevelopment) {
  config.plugins.push(new BannerAfterMinimizePlugin({
    banner: fs.readFileSync(
      path.resolve(cjsDirname, 'LICENSE'),
      'utf8'
    ),
    raw: true // LICENCE is already commented
  }));
}
// NOTE:
// in my case cjsDirname is runtime calculated string that points to package root
// construct your paths to file contents you want to bannerise as you see fit
// or just pass inline string as you do in your OP (const banner = [].join('\n');)
```

Note that I do not use *Babel Minify Webpack Plugin* as you do, but use [built in optimisation facilities](https://webpack.js.org/configuration/optimization/), i.e.

```js
// ----------------
// OPTIMISATION
config.optimization = {
  minimize: !(tierIsDevelopment || tierIsTesting),
  minimizer: [
    new TerserPlugin({
      test: /\.m?js(\?.*)?$/i,
      // include: '',
      // exclude: '',
      parallel: true,
      // minify: (file, sourceMap) => {},
      extractComments: false,
      // https://github.com/terser/terser#minify-options
      terserOptions: {
        // ecma: undefined,
        // https://github.com/terser/terser#parse-options
        parse: {},
        // https://github.com/terser/terser#compress-options
        compress: {
          drop_console: !(tierIsDevelopment || tierIsTesting)
        },
        // https://github.com/terser/terser#mangle-options
        mangle: false,
        module: false,
        // https://github.com/terser/terser#format-options
        format: {
          comments: false
        },
        sourceMap: false,
        toplevel: false,
        nameCache: null,
        ie8: false,
        // keep_classnames: undefined,
        keep_fnames: false,
        safari10: false
      }
    })
  ]
}
```

and so probably should you as it is [DEPRECIATED](https://github.com/webpack-contrib/babel-minify-webpack-plugin).

References:

- https://github.com/webpack/webpack/blob/master/lib/BannerPlugin.js
- https://github.com/webpack/webpack-sources
- https://webpack.js.org/contribute/plugin-patterns/

Comment: Wow... You saved me. That was just perfect. Just had to move it to commonjs to make it work and change the path and everything worked! Basically all i did was change from `import { ConcatSource } from 'webpack-sources';` to `const { ConcatSource } = require('webpack-sources');
` and add `module.exports = BannerAfterMinimizePlugin;` at the end of the file